# Use Parse.Query to count for an array of values

Tags: javascript, arrays, parse-platform

I want to perform a Parse.Query count operation against an array of Pointer values and return an array of count values.  Is this possible?  I imagine it looks something like:

```
var arrays = _.map(arrayOfIds, function (n){
            var pointer = new Parse.User();
            pointer.id = n;
            return array
          });

query.containedIn("key", arrays);
        query.count({
          success: function (results) {
```

When I do this however, results is a single value instead of an array of values for each item in arrays.

Comment: Please clarify.  Do you want to know how many objects there are (an integer result), or do you want to fetch those objects?  If you begin with an array of ids, and the corresponding objects in the database have not been deleted, then you know how many objects there are with arrayOfIds.length, no count or query required.

Comment: Not in this case.  The numbers could be different because the array of Ids is for a pointer and the search for the number of objects with a particular pointer in a different table pointers could (likely would) produce a different count result than the array of Ids.  To be clear, I'm looking for an array of integer results that correspond for pointers identified by the array of Ids.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @danialzahid94 I can not recall if I found an answer to this question at this time.  I think the best case would be to use _.each to apply the query to each element in arrays and collect each of the results.  If you tell me more about your problem maybe I can be helpful.